# Показать картинку поверх формы при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css

На сайте есть форма с подпиской на рассылки от mailchimp. При нажатии кнопки "Подписаться" поверх этой формы нужно вывести картинку. Готовых решений в сети не нашел (скорее всего плохо искал), а сам сообразить как это сделать не могу. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Нужен пример кода формы или картинка, показывающая как всё должно выглядеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повесить событие на кнопку, по которому и лепить картинку на нужный блок поверх него.

С помощью `this.parentElement` определяем контейнер, в котором расположена форма подписки. В него уже вставляем требуемое изображение. С помощью css выравниванием, делаем поверх и т.д, что требуется. Если нужно, можно и удалить его через время тем же JS

Comment: В итоге практически так и сделал. Два дива, в одном картинка, у него изначально в стилях display:none, во втором форма, у него display:block. При нажатии кнопки меняется параметр display у каждого из дивоф. Теперь необходимо сделать так, чтобы эта штука срабатывала только при верно введенных данных в форму, но это уже не относится к первоначальному вопросу.